# Nested arrays with 4 levels using Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

This array is output from my php by sending to Symfony.

```
    Array
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Localizar Peças
                    [children] => Array
                        (

                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => GM (Chevrolet) 
                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64
                                    [children2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Agile
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_68
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Capô
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_76
                                                                )

                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Condensador
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_82
                                                                )

                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Farol
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_79
                                                                )

                                                            [3] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Lanterna
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_80
                                                                )

                                                            [4] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Painel Frontal
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_78
                                                                )

                                                            [5] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Para-choques
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_84
                                                                )

                                                            [6] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Para-lama
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_77
                                                                )

                                                            [7] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Radiador
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_81
                                                                )

                                                            [8] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Ventoinha
                                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_68_83
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Astra
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_69
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Celta
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_72
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Classic
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_70
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Corsa
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_71
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Cruze
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_73
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [6] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Montana
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_74
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [7] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Prisma
                                                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130_64_75
                                                    [children3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )


                        )

                    [column] => 1
                    [href] => /index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=130
                )

        )

)
```

In the .twig file I am not able to assemble a code for correct display, it displays only the first and second level of the array, how do I display the third and fourth level as well? My .twig looks like this:

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>
          <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ category.name }}</div>
          </b></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu dropdown-inner">
                    {% for child2 in children2 %}
                    <li> <a href="{{ child2.href }}" >{{ child2.name }}</a> // level 3 here -> no works </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %} </div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
        </li>
        ....
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

An example of how output should be would be like this.

Localizar Peças -> GM (Chevrolet) -> Agile -> Capô

But the way it is, I can only display it in .twig / html here.

Localizar Peças -> GM (Chevrolet)

I need someone to help me understand what I'm doing wrong, because, in the example above, it still does not show the third level of the array. I think I'm looping incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, I removed the duplication and left only this, which is easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looping the right variables. In your example `children` is not known as you didn't set it yet.

You could do as followed:

```
{% for category in categories%}
 {% for child in category.children %}
  {{ child.name }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or

```
{% for category in categories %}
 {% set children = category.children %}
 {% for child in children %}
  {{ child.name }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The second method is using `set` to assign the children variable to `category.children`. Only now you can iterate over these.

To have 4 or unlimited loops over your templates until no more children f.e. you'll have to call the same twig template from within the template like this: **Category.html.twig**

```
{% for child in category.children %}
  {% include "Category.html.twig" with { "category": child } %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will continue looping until all categories are looped and their children, this works because I'm passing the variable category as the child which will then be used in the next call of the twig file. So the child becomes the new category variable.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong yet. I can not display the third level.